# Video as a Splash Screen instead of Picture

Tags: android, audio, video, splash-screen

I am doing the Android Programming Tutorial on Splash Screens where you show a picture or text for 5 Seconds than it goes to the Main Application. My Question is..Instead of Text or Pictures I want to display a Video File for 5 Seconds before it goes to the Next page of the Application.

I am not talking about when the Application Loads I am talking about when it is Loaded and you program it to display something on a Separate Java & XML page to display something then move to something else..here is my current code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle SplashScreen1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(SplashScreen1);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
    ourSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.Player.Splash.STARTINGPOINT");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
}
```

So What Do I do to make it display a  Video Media file without the Start/Stop etc..

Answer (score 17):

1) Create SplashScreen.java class.

2) Create a raw folder inside res directory(res/raw).

3) Paste your mp4 video file in this raw folder(if you don't have any sample      mp4, you can download from the below link). http://www.mediafire.com/download/p05ki89i2dt5x2x/splash.mp4

4) Then add the following code in your SplashScreen.java class.

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
        setContentView(videoHolder);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);
        videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);

        videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                jump();
            }
        });
        videoHolder.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        jump();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    jump();
    return true;
}

private void jump() {
    if (isFinishing())
        return;
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

}

Note: splash_activity.xml is not required.

Comment: Is it possible to center the video?

Comment: @Thecave3 yes, you can use a VideoView inside a FrameLayout and add the layout_gravity="center" attribute

Comment: @ArielCarbonaro FYI I've implemented this solution months ago and it turns out in a big quality loss. I think that the best solution is to split the video and create an animation view.

Answer (score 9):

I hope this will help you. You just create a simple [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) for create a splash screen for the video.

Checkout the **[source code](https://code.google.com/p/vid-splash-screen-android/source/checkout)** hear and [simple steps what is the best practice to create a splash screen](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/09/how-to-create-splash-activity-best.html)

Answer (score 6):

Use a `MediaPlayer` along with a `VideoView`. You can then "listen" for when the video playback is done, by setting an `OnCompletionListener` on your `MediaPlayer`.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html
And here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Also, pay special attention to the state diagram on the `MediaPlayer` reference page. It can be a bit tricky and has been known to trip a few people up.

Answer (score 1):

```
imgAnim=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.animimage);

String uriPath = "android.resource://com.petnvet/" + R.drawable.vidio;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
imgAnim.setVideoURI(uri);
imgAnim.requestFocus();
imgAnim.start();
//  imgAnim.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.myapplication/" + R.drawable.vidio);
int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 3000;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for adding video. In case you need to add controls on video like pause or seek etc. you can add them with:

```
vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

Rest of the code:

```
VideoView vv;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    vv=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri path=Uri.parse("android:resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.hello);
    vv.setVideoURI(path);
    vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

   vv.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
   {
       @Override
       public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
           Intent in=new Intent(splash.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
           finish();

       }
   });
    vv.start();
```

Comment: There is no need to put same answer again and angain with wrong code