# Splash screen using video

Tags: android, video, splash-screen

Is it possible to create a splash screen for my android app using video? I want to play this video before the app starts.
I have a done a simple splash screen but I'm just using a simple image with no animation. But there this video I've created(4 seconds video) that i want to replace with the image. Is it possible? 
Sorry bad English. Hope you guys can help me

Comment: yes it is possible please visit the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221155/video-as-a-splash-screen-instead-of-picture?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already questions with answers on StackOverflow that can help you achieve this:

[How do I make a splash screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)

[Integrating video file in android app as app background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830111/integrating-video-file-in-android-app-as-app-background) (see accepted answer)