# Splash screen video cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, apache, cordova

i'm using apache cordova, i need to set a video like a splashscreen, but how can i do it?

```
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
```

i test changing the files by a video, but it doesnt work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video as a Splash Screen instead of Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221155/video-as-a-splash-screen-instead-of-picture)

Comment: Try using an flash or animated gif . You do know you can easily convert your video file to gif right?