# Change the splash screen img to mp4

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I want to change the splash screen in my APP from img to mp4 but the problem when I run the APP  see a black screen.

What is the problem?

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this , QuranDataActivity.class);
        SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        SplashActivity.this.finish();
      }
    }, 4000);

  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video as a Splash Screen instead of Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221155/video-as-a-splash-screen-instead-of-picture)

Comment: Please approve the answer if it was correct

Comment: I do, thanks man for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `VideoView` just add it in you SplashScreenActivity layout xml and then programmatically play video in it.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

     // For playing Video
     VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
     String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
     view.setMediaController(null); // to hide the controllers
     view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
     view.start();         

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
               /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
           Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this , QuranDataActivity.class);
           SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
           SplashActivity.this.finish();
          }
       }, 4000);

   }

 }
```

Comment: you have forgot to set content view 
        `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);`

Comment: @sausagerus oops my mistake .. i actually copied the boilerplate code from the question i only added the video playback code part .. that why i missed it. :D